# Pass Array Values from webpart.ts to Main.tsx

Tags: spfx-webparts, custom-web-part-property

I am fetching data from webpart.ts using this.properties.data
and present it as list items in Main.tsx. However, It only displays as a string like Select Google rather than

- select
- Google

What am I missing?

webpart.ts

```
  IMylinkWebPartProps
> {

  private temp = new Set();

  private handleClick() {
    this.temp.add(this.properties.linkName);
    let array = [];
    this.temp.forEach(v => array.push(v + "\n"));
    this.properties.data = [...array];

    debugger;
  }
//codes continue
```

main.tsx

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IMylinkProps> {
    console.log(this.state);
    let test = [this.props.data];
    console.log("test=", test);
return (
//codes continue....
)
```

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let test = [this.props.data];
```

Change to

```
let test = this.props.data;
```

sorry, I do not need to create another array while assigning to the test.